# Creating a vector of string matches

Tags: r, string, match, grepl

I have data as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("id var
              1  thisstring
              2  otherstring
              3  notthisone")
```

I am trying to get a vector of all strings in column `var` that contain `string`.

If I do:

```
grepl("string", dat$var)
```

I get:

```
[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

What I want to get is:

```
matches <-  c("thisstring", "otherstring")
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `value = TRUE` in `grep`:

```r
grep("string", dat$var, value = TRUE)
#[1] "thisstring"  "otherstring"
```

Answer (score 6):

```
dat[grepl("string",var),var]
```

Ouptut:

```
[1] "thisstring"  "otherstring"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `%like%` like this:

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("id var
              1  thisstring
              2  otherstring
              3  notthisone")

dat$var[dat$var %like% 'string']
#> [1] "thisstring"  "otherstring"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using `str_subset`

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(dat$var, "string")
[1] "thisstring"  "otherstring"
```

Answer (score 0):

and perhaps

```
dat$var[which(grepl('string', dat$var) == TRUE)] 
[1] "thisstring"  "otherstring"
```

Comment: This is like @langtang's answer, but with two unnecessary additions (eg, `which()` and `==TRUE`).

Comment: Similar, but, the `which(` makes it different, and makes it easier (for me) to reason about.